# Systemd: wait till port is open to start service or to declare a service as started

Tags: systemd

I have some services ( A, B, C) that require another service (activemq) to be "active" and have all required ports listening for connections, prior to start them. 
Services B and C rely on A, which relies on activemq and its ports to be listening (specially port 61616).

The problem I have is that systemd flags the activemq service as "active" before activemq finishes opening all ports. So my service (A) starts and then dies.

what I tried:

set: 
Restart=on-success (or always)
it works, but I need to do it for all services (A B C ). And I don't want to apply that kind of rule.

What it works is adding in service A:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
```

then service A starts properly and so B and C without any further configuration (other than the respective "After=" and "Requires=" which is set for all services: A, B and C). 
But I don't think is a proper/clean solution.

I also tried other options in [Service] but none work, e.g Type=fork, etc

What I want is:

- tell systemd to only flag the activemq service as "active" once all ports are listening (there are four of them) or at least the last port, which is the one causing issues: 61616
  or
- start service A only after port 61616 is listening (some kind of Require=tcp/61616 or something like that)

The activemq.service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Activemq Servoce
After=local-fs.target                                                                                                                                                                      
After=network.target                                                                                                                                                                       

[Service]                                                                                                                                                                                  
Type=simple                                                                                                                                                                                
SuccessExitStatus=0 143                                                                                                                                                                    
ExecStart=/usr/bin/activemq console                                                                                                                                                        
User=activemq                                                                                                                                                                              
Group=activemq                                                                                                                                                                             
Restart=always
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What does activemq's unit file look like, and are you open to modifying it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on:

> systemd flags the activemq service as "active" before activemq finishes opening all ports.

and:

> [Service A] relies on activemq and its ports to be listening (specially port 61616).

... you may way to modify systemd's understanding of the service's status beyond "process is running" to "process is running *and* that port is open". That seems simpler to me than modifying all the subsequent unit files to check for the open port. One way to do that would be with an [ExecStartPost option](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) that  busy-loop waits for the OS to indicate that the port is now being listened to.

An example:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/timeout 30 sh -c 'while ! ss -H -t -l -n sport = :61616 | grep -q "^LISTEN.*:61616"; do sleep 1; done'
```

This gives systemd one command to execute after ExecStart. That one command is `timeout`, which provides a fail-stop for situations where the main application does not successfully start -- and listen to the port -- within 30 seconds. That `timeout` command wraps a simple `sh -c ...` shell loop which tests for the port being listened to. The shell loop itself runs until the `ss ... | grep ...` condition is true, with a one-second `sleep` between each test.

The [`ss` command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) has these options:

- `-H` -- suppress the header (this option isn't essential, but I like to remove noise)
- `-t` -- display only TCP sockets
- `-l` -- display only listening sockets
- `-n` -- do not resolve service numbers into names -- keep them as the number, so that we can `grep` them later
- `sport = :61616` -- a filter that restricts the output to entries that have a source port of 61616

The `grep` command then looks for a line that starts with "LISTEN" and is followed at some point by the string ":61616", indicating that the main application has begun listening on that port. The `-q` flag tells grep to just report success or failure, and to emit no output, since we only care whether the line exists or not.

During startup of the main application, systemd show a status of "activating (start-post)" until the ExecStartPost command exits. If the application starts successfully and opens the port within 30 seconds, systemd updates the status to "active (running)".  In case of failure, systemd will -- in your example of `Restart=always`, restart the whole process -- but otherwise report "failed (Result: exit-code)" and point to the ExecStartPost command with its exit code "(code=exited, status=124)", indicating that the command timed out, and will terminate the main process.